# Is there any third party libraries are available in Android for capturing image?

Tags: android, android-camera

Now I try to developing an application related to Image processing, for that I must need camera functionality. I don't wish to use default device camera intent, instead of that, any libraries or other open source code are available. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you mean by image processing?you will perform image processing after capturing image right?

Comment: Yes you are correct, here i'm adding color filter eg. Grayscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applying GrayScale effect you have various libraries available

**1 marvinproject**

You can give a try to marvinproject. http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

```
MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/image.jpg");
MarvinImagePlugin plugin = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.color.grayScale.jar");
plugin.process(image,image,null,MarvinImageMask.NULL_MASK, false);
image.update(); 
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/image_output.jpg");
```

**2 aviary**

http://www.aviary.com/android

Comment: My Question related to capture an image, applying filter is second part

Answer (score 0):

follow along  with [Building A Camera App](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) in the developer docs.

that should  teach  you how to use the Camera API to get the picture that you can apply a filter too.